# Teaching assistant bash script to automate the process of finding, compiling, and running .java files

Tags: java, bash, automation

## Background:

I posted a question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469680/teaching-assistant-bash-script-to-automate-the-process-of-finding-compiling-an and received some really good advice. Now I'd like to take my process one step further.

## Summary of Design:

I'm a TA in University looking to automate testing my student's java code. I am also using this opportunity to grow in my bash skills because I feel like they could be better. My current bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

list='/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/output/list.txt'
score='/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/output/score.txt'

> "$list"
> "$score"

find "$1" -name '*.java' >> "$list"

exec 3< "$list"

while IFS='' read -r -u 3 line || [ -n "$line" ]
do

    read -p "> $line (Press Enter to continue)"

    echo "the next file is $line" >> "$score"

    open -a "Xcode" "$line" 

    javac -d "/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs" "$line" >> class && echo compiled >> "$score" || echo not compiled >> "$score"

    echo "standard in string" | cd "/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs" java "$class" >> "$score"
done
```

## Point of Contention

Currently, everything works up until the last line before the done. For some strange reason, the output from the **java "$class"** is not appended to **"$score"**. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

## Additional Goals

A) I would like to be able to take in additional parameters for my script so that I don't need to keep editing it for each new assignment. For example in:

```
find "$1" -name '*.java' >> "$list"
```

I would like to be able to replace the **'*.java'** with **'*string.java'***. I know that I can obtain the string as $2 as a command arg for the script, but **'$2.java'** does not seem to be the correct way of going about this. As an example: say I only want to look at a subset of .java files that end color.java, I would like to be able to say

```
bash script.sh directory color
```

and have that perform the task. If there is no $2, the code should default to **'*.java'**.

Comment: Hi again. I am glad you formulated your question quite well. Good job there! Wish you luck.

Comment: Could you further explain to us, what the last line is supposed to output? An example would be best, if possible.

Comment: Please correct error in the `javac` line with `class` word with `"$class"`.

Answer (score 1):

## My Solution:

After speaking with my professor I have worked out a solution. I would like to note the new script, and what the problems with the old script were, and what changed we made to make this work:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/output/list.txt
score=/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/output/score.txt
runs=/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs

> "$list"
> "$score"

rm -r "$runs"/*

find "$1" -name "*$3.java" >> "$list"

exec 3< "$list"

while IFS='' read -r -u 3 line || [ -n "$line" ]
do

    read -p "> $line (Press Enter to continue)"

    echo "the next file is $line" >> "$score"

    open -a "Xcode" "$line" 

    javac -d "$runs" "$line" && echo compiled >> "$score" || echo not compiled >> "$score"

    class=$(basename "$line")
    class=${class%.java}

    cd "$runs"

    echo "$2" | java -cp "$runs" ${class} >> "$score"

done
```

### Explanation:

list, score, and runs all refer to paths on my computer, in the future, I'd like to make this solution more general for any computer. The lines:

```
> "$list"
> "$score"
```

Reinitialize these paths to be empty. In order to reinitialize the runs folder to be empty we use:

```
rm -r "$runs"/*
```

Which recursively removes anything inside the run directory. A word of

#### **Caution**: because of the asterisk, if runs is improperly set, you may do irreversible damage to your computer.

The code is the same until here:

```
class=$(basename "$line")
class=${class%.java}
```

In this step, we grab only the last item in the class directory, and then we remove the .class part of the name, because running:

```
java code.class
```

is really telling the jvm to do:

```
java code.class.class
```

and so we will encounter errors.

In the last step we use curly braces instead of quotes {} to refer to the file name:

```
echo "$2" | java -cp "$runs" ${class} >> "$score"
```

And other than making the $2 and $3 be assigned at execution as opposed to when the script is run, the code is the same.

I hope that if someone runs into this issue in the future, this answer will be helpful. I will be refactoring a more general purpose script for this usage and I may post it as an addendum in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing Java. You're doing

```
 cd "/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs" java "$class" >> "$score"
```

The cd command sees 3 arguments and ignores "java" and "$class".

Try instead:

```
cd "/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs"
echo "standard in string" | java "$class" >> "$score"
```

Or if your CLASSPATH environment variable doesn't contain `.` as one of the paths, you may explicitly set the classpath without changing directory:

```
echo "standard in string" | java -cp "/Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs" "$class" >> "$score"
```

Comment: I've amended my code, and now all I get is "Error: Could not find or load main class" for every compiled file in /Users/ajm/Desktop/170Grading/runs, but when I look in the run folder I see many compiled .class files. And if I look inside score.txt, every javac is showing compiled.

Comment: I've changed to the second case and tried that, and I still receive the "Error: Could not find or load main class".